# Git: How to clone a forked repo based on another forked repo?

Tags: git, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree

Every single time when I start working on a prototype I will fork it from a prototype framework. The framework has all the goodness necessary to start with a project.

After the first round of user testing, I will want the forked repo (version A) to stay at its current look (locked down). So in the future, I will be able to refer back to it.

Then to get the prototype ready for second round of user testing, I will clone the forked repo so I have a version B.

And sometimes there might be changes I will be doing on the original prototype framework that I want it to percolate through to version A and version B.

-

Is cloning the correct way to create a separate version?
How do I remove dependencies from both version A and B?
How do I keep the dependencies to the original prototype framework?

- I am using bitbucket and sourcetree.

Answer (score 0):

I have spoken to my colleague, it seems that branching is all I need.